# Magento Fishpig Wordpress module - Creating a custom post list

Tags: wordpress, magento, fishpig

This should be simple, but for some reason it is not. I simply want to be able to load in my own template file and have access to the $this->getPosts() method.

I have tried:

```
<block type="wordpress/post_list" name="blog_header" template="unleaded/fishpig/header.phtml"/>
```

and then in my template:

```
<?php $_posts = $this->getPosts() ?>
<?php foreach ($_posts as $_post) : ?>
     <?php echo $_post->getAuthor() ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

This does not work. Looking at the main List.php block file, the collection is returned based on a "wrapper", but I can't seem to find what that is.

Does anyone else have a code sample for getting a post list in any template for Magento?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was a simple matter of grabbing the block first. There's other ways, but this worked for me.

```
<?php $_block = $this->getPostListBlock() ?>
<?php $_posts = $_block->getPosts() ?>
```